# MySQL & PHP special character issue

Tags: php, mysql

I am using MySQL 5.5 version

when i try to insert the ‘ special character in database it is automatically converted into â€™ .

i changed the database character set to utf8 & character_set_connection to utf8 but i unable to get the expected result.

how to solve this issue ?

kindly help on this

Answer (score 0):

You need to check how you are sending the data.
If the character set in the database is utf-8, you need to send like that to.

Try to encode the data before, like that:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablex(field) VALUES('".utf8_encode($mydata)."')";
```

Answer (score -2):

It is important to make sure that every part of your connection is using utf8, otherwise you `will` run into problems.

Below we will create a utf8 connection to the database, perform `set names` which is vitally important and then write using a utf8_encode method.

```
mysql_connect("host", "user", "pass");
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mysql_select_db("my_db");
mysql_query("set names 'utf8'");

$sql = "INSERT INTO `table`(`foo`) VALUES('".utf8_encode($bar)."')";
```

Comment: While this may be correct, an explanation would be helpful.